# Changing pictures by clicking on the TImage component - Delphi

Tags: delphi, click, image

I want to **change picture** loaded into **Image1** - from one called **1active.png** to second called **1inactive.png** and vice versa **by clicking** on the Image1 component.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ingredients**:

- 1 boolean variable
- 1 TImage component
- 1 line added to form OnCreate event handler
- 1 TImage.OnClick event handler

**instructions**:

1)  Create a boolean variable in the private section of your form declaration.  For this example, call this variable fImageActive.

```
private
  fImageActive : boolean;
```

2) From the form designer, drop (or select an existing) TImage component on the form and select the onClick event, and double click to switch into editing.  Then add the following code:

```
  fImageActive := not fImageActive;
  if fImageActive then
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('1active.png')
  else
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('1inactive.png')
```

3) From the form designer, find the picture property and click the ellipsis to load the 1active.png file for starters.

4) Click on the form, find the event named "OnCreate", double click and add the following code (this will set the initial state):

```
  fImageActive := true;
```

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using D2009 as you can load a png file in Image1.

If you don't want to distribute your images along with your application (as skamradt's solution implies), you have to include them as resources:
Add the png to your project: Use menu "**Project | Resources...**" and add the files.
Name them accordingly to get something like:

```
 1active.png    RCData  PngImage_Active  
 1inactive.png  RCData  PngImage_Inactive
```

In your Click event, you'll need some state indicator to know which one to display (like skamradt).
I used the Image1.hint to tell which image is loaded (quick and dirty, for demo purpose).

Use the LoadImgFromPngResource proc below to load the appropriate png image:

```
procedure LoadImgFromPngResource(const AResName: string; DestImage: TImage);
var
  png: TPngImage;
begin
  png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    png.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, AResName);
    DestImage.Picture.Assign(png);
  finally
    png.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Image1.Hint <> 'Active' then
  begin
    LoadImgFromPngResource('PngImage_Active', Image1);
    Image1.Hint := 'Active';
  end
  else
  begin
    LoadImgFromPngResource('PngImage_Inactive', Image1);
    Image1.Hint := 'Inactive';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load both images into the resource file of your project, and in runtime you can read the pics from the resource file and load them into the timage on the OnClick. The version of Delphi I'm currently using (6) does not have native support for PNG files, but I think latter version do

Comment: bBuilt-in PNG support wasn't introduced until Delphi 2009.

Comment: That's for the extra input Mason